# main() creates undefined error when running starter file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, program-entry-point

I am going to be writing a program with this starter file provided to me by my instructor. The issue is is that the file she gave us does not run. I don't know if this is because I am using IDLE, or if the code only runs on certain operating systems.

For example, I use Windows, but my teacher uses both Windows and Linux systems. I cannot get a hold of her to figure out the issue, so I was hoping you guys could.

Currently, when I run the starter file, I get an error:

```
TypeError: main() is not defined.
```

When I switch `main()` for `GUI()` at the bottom of the program, I get a new error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rootWindow'
```

This is the full code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import tk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,rootWindow):
        self.label = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Hellow World!")
        self.label.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.button1=ttk.Button(rootWindow,text="Hello",command=self.hello)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.button2=ttk.Button(rootWindow,text="Bye",command=self.bye)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=2)

    def bye(self):
        self.label.config(text="GoodbyeWorld!")

    def hello(self):
        self.label.config(text="HelloWorld!")

    def main():
        global label
        rootWindow = Tk()

        gui = GUI(rootWindow)
        rootWindow.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: `GUI()` requires the `rootWindow` argument.

Comment: `main` isn't defined. `GUI.main` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

1. You need to unindent the `main` function, because otherwise you can't just call `main` because it is a part of the `GUI` class.
2. The imports are messed up. You need to `import tkinter as ttk` because otherwise `ttk` is undefined, and `import Tk` instead of `import tk`.

Note that I am using Python 3, so yours may be slightly different if you're using Python 2.

The full corrected code is below:

```py
import tkinter as ttk
from tkinter import Tk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,rootWindow):
        self.label = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Hellow World!")
        self.label.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.button1=ttk.Button(rootWindow,text="Hello",command=self.hello)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.button2=ttk.Button(rootWindow,text="Bye",command=self.bye)
        self.button2.grid(row=0,column=2)

    def bye(self):
        self.label.config(text="GoodbyeWorld!")

    def hello(self):
        self.label.config(text="HelloWorld!")

def main():
    global label
    rootWindow = Tk()

    gui = GUI(rootWindow)
    rootWindow.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: I understand now, this makes a lot of sense and was a great help with getting the starter file to run! Thanks a lot!